# react display array of objects in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array of object, i need to show them in a table,

I am stuck at how to display adjustedAmount, paidAmount and cost type ?

Here is the obj i have :

```
const datdfa = [
{
  index: 500,
  schudule_number: "11010",
  scheduleAvailableBudget: 1598000,
  budgetedqty: 2000,
  paidQty: 3,
  availableBalance: 1595633,
  adjustedAmount: [{ "Labour Cost": 3, "Material Cost": 0 }],
  paidAmount: [{ "Labour Cost": 1059, "Material Cost": 1059 }]
},
{
  index: 2016,
  schudule_number: "11020",
  scheduleAvailableBudget: 21600,
  budgetedqty: 12,
  paidQty: 10,
  availableBalance: 3663,
  adjustedAmount: [{}],
  paidAmount: [{ "Labour Cost": 468, "Material Cost": 468 }]
}
];
```

And here is the table to display

```
{datdfa?.map((s, d) => {
    let uniqueWSID = `row_${d}`;
      return (
          ...
          <td valign="middle">
              {
                  (s.adjustedAmount)?.map((ad) => {
                      return(
                          <td>{ad.key}</td> // this does not shows up
                      );
                  })
              }
          </td>
```

and i have created a sandbox link - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-fire-hgmr3?file=/src/App.js:108-707)

What am i making wrong / how to display it in the table ?

Comment: your sandbox have empty please update the code and fork

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-fire-hgmr3?file=/src/App.js - it has been updated

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your sandbox, here is the solution (https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-mendeleev-7nrke?file=/src/App.js):

```
const datdfa = [
{
index: 500,
schudule_number: "11010",
scheduleAvailableBudget: 1598000,
budgetedqty: 2000,
paidQty: 3,
availableBalance: 1595633,
adjustedAmount: [{ LabourCost: 3, MaterialCost: 0 }],
paidAmount: [{ LabourCost: 1059, MaterialCost: 1059 }]
},
{
index: 2016,
schudule_number: "11020",
scheduleAvailableBudget: 21600,
budgetedqty: 12,
paidQty: 10,
availableBalance: 3663,
adjustedAmount: [{}],
paidAmount: [{ LabourCost: 468, MaterialCost: 468 }]
}
];

export default function App() {
  return (
 <div>
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>index</th>
          <th>schudule_number</th>
          <th>scheduleAvailableBudget</th>
          <th>budgetedqty</th>
          <th>paidQty</th>
          <th>availableBalance</th>
          <th>adjustedAmount</th>
          <th>paidAmount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        {datdfa.map((column) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{column.index}</td>
            <td>{column.schudule_number}</td>
            <td>{column.scheduleAvailableBudget}</td>
            <td>{column.budgetedqty}</td>
            <td>{column.paidQty}</td>
            <td>{column.availableBalance}</td>
            <td>
              {column.adjustedAmount.map((amount) => (
                <span>
                  <span>{"LabourCost " + amount.LabourCost}</span>
                  <span>{"Material Cost " + amount.MaterialCost}</span>
                </span>
              ))}
            </td>
            <td>
              {column.paidAmount.map((amount) => (
                <span>
                  <span>{"LabourCost " + amount.LabourCost}</span>
                  <span>{"Material Cost " + amount.MaterialCost}</span>
                </span>
              ))}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your sandbox is an empty. Anyway I think that might be a problem with part where you map and show , try that:

```
  {s.adjustedAmount?.map((ad) => (
    <td>{ad.key}</td> 
  ))}
```

@edit
Here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-violet-2feyh?file=/src/App.js)

Basically you shouldn't create array elements like that, usually it is better to have objects with `{name: "someName", value: 1}` for example so then you can just map through `name` and `value` of each one. That's how I made it in the sandbox. It is easier to map through all values. In this example you have only 2 elements but if you would have like 1000 or more you will have to hardcode each one... which will waste so much time.

Comment: forked sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-fire-jdwb7

Comment: @Learning and which line is not working in the sandbox?

Comment: line 67 and 68, i have hard coded it, i need these values to be coming from array of objects